# Getting error when trying to load node packages in package.json file

Tags: json, node.js, package.json

## I executed this command to install packages & put its references in package.json file.

```
 npm install gulp browserify gulp-browserify gulp-clean gulp-concat gulp-jshint gulp-util gulp-embedlr gulp-livereload tiny-lr connect-livereload express --save-dev
```

## I am getting this error while launching this command:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_mod
ules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "gulp" "browserify" "gulp-browserify" "gulp-clean" "
gulp-concat" "gulp-jshint" "gulp-util" "gulp-embedlr" "gulp-livereload" "tiny-lr" "connect
-livereload" "express" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! file C:\wamp\www\Consult\package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected end of input
npm ERR! File: C:\wamp\www\Consult\package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\wamp\www\Consult\npm-debug.log
```

I am using windows machine with npm installed. This is my npm-debug.log file

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'gulp',
1 verbose cli   'browserify',
1 verbose cli   'gulp-browserify',
1 verbose cli   'gulp-clean',
1 verbose cli   'gulp-concat',
1 verbose cli   'gulp-jshint',
1 verbose cli   'gulp-util',
1 verbose cli   'gulp-embedlr',
1 verbose cli   'gulp-livereload',
1 verbose cli   'tiny-lr',
1 verbose cli   'connect-livereload',
1 verbose cli   'express',
1 verbose cli   '--save-dev' ]
2 info using npm@2.5.1
3 info using node@v0.12.0
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
5 verbose stack Error: Failed to parse json
5 verbose stack Unexpected end of input
5 verbose stack     at parseError (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:378:25)
5 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:85:51)
5 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:59:33
5 verbose stack     at evalmachine.<anonymous>:336:14
5 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:102:5
5 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (evalmachine.<anonymous>:99:15)
6 verbose cwd C:\wamp\www\Consult
7 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
8 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "gulp" "browserify" "gulp-browserify" "gulp-clean" "gulp-concat" "gulp-jshint" "gulp-util" "gulp-embedlr" "gulp-livereload" "tiny-lr" "connect-livereload" "express" "--save-dev"
9 error node v0.12.0
10 error npm  v2.5.1
11 error file C:\wamp\www\Consult\package.json
12 error code EJSONPARSE
13 error Failed to parse json
13 error Unexpected end of input
14 error File: C:\wamp\www\Consult\package.json
15 error Failed to parse package.json data.
15 error package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
15 error
15 error This is not a bug in npm.
15 error Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse
16 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a package.json file at C:\wamp\www\Consult\package.json.

The package.json file specifies which packages npm should install.

Since the file exists, npm defaults to using it but fails to parse the contents as JSON.

**You can either fix the package.json file, or delete it and run your command again.**

I recommend checking out this guide: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json

Comment: I reran the command after deleting package.json file but it didn't created a new one. Do I need to do npm init ?

Comment: yup, that will create an initial package.json

Answer (score 0):

```
13 Failed to parse json
13 error Unexpected end of input
14 error File: C:\wamp\www\Consult\package.json
```

You have a typo/syntax error in `C:\wamp\www\Consult\package.json` file.